# In NHibernate 4 how can I stop PostgreSQL 9.4 from building up a bunch of 'idle in transaction' connections?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, transactions

I have a unit of work object that uses transactions by default. Sometimes, I use it only to make a query then the object is not needed anymore. This is what I'm trying:

```
private void Cleanup()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Transactions && transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && transaction.IsActive)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                transaction.Dispose();
            }


            if (!IsStateless)
            {
                session.Close();
                session.Dispose();
            }
               else
            {
                statelessSession.Close();
                statelessSession.Dispose();

            }
                } catch (Exception) { }

        }


   public void Dispose()
    {
        Cleanup();
    }

    ~BaseUnitOfWork()
    {
        Cleanup();
    }
```

I also make sure to enclose the unit of work in a using bracket to make sure Dispose() is called. Nevertheless, if I quickly click on my website and force a bunch of these sessions to be opened and presumably cleanly dealt with with the above, I'm still getting:

```
  Timeout while getting a connection from pool.
```

This is because I have too many idle connections:

[image: This from the pgAdmin III Server status window]

How can I make all these idle connections go away? Am I disposing my session correctly or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current incarnation. Seems to work fine.

```
 private void Cleanup(bool fromDispose)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Transactions && transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && !transaction.WasRolledBack)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();

                }
            }catch (Exception e) 
            {}
            try{
                if (!IsStateless && session.IsOpen)
                {
                    session.Close();
                    session.Dispose();
                }
                   else if (session.IsOpen)
                {
                    statelessSession.Close();
                    statelessSession.Dispose();

                }
                    } catch (Exception e)
            { }

            }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            Cleanup(true);
        }

        ~BaseUnitOfWork()
        {
            Cleanup(false);
        }
```

If I enclose my unit of work in a 'using' statement dispose is triggered when it goes out of scope. Otherwise, they will all eventually close when the garbage collector gets around to disposing the object.